# How to use Keyboard Shortcut on azure portal to search on german keyboard?

Tags: azure, azureportal

The [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) has a search field on a resource group pane. The placeholder says I can access this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.
[image: search in a resource group in azure portal]

On the german keyboard layout the <kbd>/</kbd> can print with <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>.

Which keys do I need to press to get to the search box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this is not supported in German keyboard by using this shortcut. But the Engineering team has plan on this as per this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/22673#issuecomment-456626078), feedback as below:

> I just got word from the engineering owner that they have added this
>   to their "work item" backlog to complete this semester. They will be
>   also be adding CTRL + SHIFT + / as a shortcut. For now this will be
>   tagged as a known issue. Will respond as I get more updates. We will
>   close this issue for now but reply if you have any followup questions.

Answer (score 1):

I actually see two search fields when looking at resource groups.

- For the one on top (searches all resources, services and docs) my workaround is G+. (moves focus to the header) and then tab.
- For the one below (that only searches the list of resource groups) my workaround is G+, (moves focus to the list header) and then tab.

(if you are in one of the search fields already, the G+ shortcuts don't work - in this case move somewhere else with a tab first)
(G+. means holding "g" and then also pressing "." (dot))

Comment: On my windows firefox crtl+. and ctrl+, is not working

Comment: thanks. Got a windows pc out and the shortcuts are the same as one the mac - i.e. g+. to move the focus to the header; this means press and hold g then also press . (dot). Changed it in the response.

Answer (score 0):

As the azure portal still seems to have issues with my german keyboard in 2021, I implemented a small userscript for tampermonkey to fix this for me.

At the moment it only supports a few shortcut keys, but i made it easy to extend with new shortcuts:

https://gist.github.com/tkoenig89/d9c2eaa9f37538abc2163ecd4e6fb28c